# search in database for similar terms

Tags: c#, sql, search, compact-framework, sql-server-ce

I have a c# application on a mobile device with a sqlce-database on it.

In the database there is one large table where i want to search for a name of a city or address. The problem is, that the citynames are from different sources, or were inserted by different people, so the cities contains for example **Saint XXX, St. YYY** and **St ZZZ**.

In my search it shouldn't matter wether I search fpr **St XXX** or for **Saint XXX**. The results should be the same

Of course this problem occures not only at the term Saint, it is just a example. I don't know yet how much, but there'll be a lot of different terms.

I had some approaches, like replacing

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(name,'St.','Saint'),'St','Saint') FROM cities WHERE name = REPLACE(REPLACE(@SearchTerm,'St.','Saint'),'St','Saint')
```

But the performance is ugly.

Also `SoundEx` doesn't really give the results I need, because Saint and St don't sound similar at all.

The citynames come from a external datasource (by mergereplication), so I can't update them on the server and I don't want to update the citynames, but use them as they are stored in the db.

How could I do the search to fit my needs?

Comment: Select name FROM cities WHERE name like '%' + @SearchTerm

Comment: this would work if the user never entered something like St. Petersburg but only Petersburg. But he should be able to enter St. Petersburg, Saint Petersburg or St Petersburg

Comment: This will be a trick, can you split your search string by space(' ') and check the string at 0th location is (St. or Saint or St) if yes  then ignore that string and send the rest of the string to the query and use this query `Select name FROM cities WHERE name like '%' + @SearchTerm + '%'`

Comment: Yeah. I could use a dictionary with `bad strings` and create my SearchTerm automatically. Sounds good to me. Thanks

Comment: Don't Forget to vote up, if it helps you....:-)

Comment: @RohitVyas - Upvoting a comment doesn't benefit your reputation.  If your comment is an answer and you want credit for it, type it into an Answer and not a Comment...

Comment: @Dems Thanks, i don't know about this...:-( :-( :-(

Answer (score 2):

Fuzzy search, the bane of every database designer...

I would split each name in the database at whitespaces and punctuation marks, and enter the resulting sub-strings into a new table "city_alias" which also includes a foreign key to the original cities table.

So for "Saint Petersburg", two aliasses would be created, "Saint" and "Petersburg". The alias "Saint" is very likely a very frequent one, so it should be ignored for search queries.

When the user enters "St.Petersburg" into the search, it would be broken up into "St" and "Petersburg". "St" is likely just as frequent as "Saint", so it should be ignored. So the alias table is searched for "Petersburg", which would return "Saint Petersburg" (as well as "Saint Petersburg-Kronstadt" or "Petersburg (Alaska)").

**Edit:** The alias table could also be populated manually with frequent misspellings (Petersbourg), nicknames (Piter), outdated names (Leningrad) or local spelling (Петербу́рг).